# Python API GET request auto generate email based upon object in JSON response

Tags: python, json, dataframe, get

I am writing a Python program for our infrastructure team that, when run, will send an API GET request to our network dashboard and return a JSON string, after which time it is then converted into a dataframe. That is working as it should but where I am having the issue is email alerts. When this program is run, if there are modems or servers offline (the JSON string/dataframe has a status object that says either "online" | "offline" per location), it will send an email alert to a certain email address. The program works seamlessly, but I cannot figure out how to incorporate the code into the program to send an email alert when the status object has an offline value.

Code Samples:

```
while option != 0:
    if option == 1:
        print ("OranizationID has been selected")
        exec(open('orgId.py').read())
    elif option == 2:
        print ("Getting network status of all sites...")
        exec(open('status.py').read())
        df.to_excel("output.xlsx")
```

This is the status file used to call the API and reponse with a JSON string then convert it to a dataframe:

```
url = "https://urlremovedfrompost"

payload={}
headers = {
  'API-Key': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, data=payload)

a = json.loads(r.text)
res = json_normalize(a)

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

df = pd.DataFrame(res)
print(df)
```

As I said all of that works perfectly, I just want to incorporate a function of some kind to send an email to a certain email address if this code is ran and the status object has offline devices, and list the devices that are offline. Tere are approximate 600 in the df. Thank you for the help!!

Comment: does the option = 0 means that the network server is offline, if it is so then you can just write the alert part after you are out of the while loop.

Comment: @Ufomammut No that is the menu options that I can select to run scripts in the program. The first script is the menu part of the main framework and when i press option 2, it runs the second snippet of code I posted, sends the GET request, and brings it in as a JSON (a = json.loads....) and then it is converted and sent to the first script where it is read onto the screen in dataframes. I was trying to do something like this: df = pd.DataFrame(res)
for status in df.status:
    if status == "offline":
        with open("contacts_file.csv") as file:
            reader = csv.reader(file)